# configure phpmailer with DKIM

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

I installed DKIM on my server following this tutorial:
http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-dkim-domainkeys-identified-mail-working-with-postfix-on-centos-using-opendkim

However phpmailer wants the following fields to use DKIM:

```
/**
* Used with DKIM DNS Resource Record
* @var string
*/
public $DKIM_selector   = '';

/**
 * Used with DKIM DNS Resource Record
 * optional, in format of email address 'you@yourdomain.com'
 * @var string
*/
public $DKIM_identity   = '';

/**
 * Used with DKIM DNS Resource Record
 * @var string
 */
public $DKIM_passphrase   = '';

/**
 * Used with DKIM DNS Resource Record
 * optional, in format of email address 'you@yourdomain.com'
 * @var string
 */
public $DKIM_domain     = '';

/**
 * Used with DKIM DNS Resource Record
 * optional, in format of email address 'you@yourdomain.com'
 * @var string
 */
public $DKIM_private    = '';
```

I know the selector and the private key. But what is the passphrase?

Also, for identy, can I just put `*@mydomain.com`?